# Tracking a value that updates every now and then upon API end point execution

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a table with a numeric value for example (81 345) now this updates every time a external company uses our endpoint, so say they executed that end point 81 345 times in the past and they request another execution, that value would update to 81 346 cause it was 81 345 PLUS THE NEW REQUEST which is 1, so it adds 1 to 81 345 which updates the value to 81 346.

Now once the value updates the number it was before the update disappears, so how do I keep track of this count, for example I need to be able to say how many updates there occurred in a day, in a week, or between a certain time period etc.

Comment: If need to be able to see the number of requests in any arbitrary time period, you need to store the time of each request.

Comment: With these numbers you could save each update as a separate entry to any preferred database. If there is literally no data to be saved (e.g. who updated what), you can just add a new item with data `{"event": "counter_update", "timestamp": 123456789}`.

Comment: if you would get current number at every midnight and keep in separated table in separated row (with date) then you could substract numbers to get how many updates was between days and weeks (but not between times in one day).

Answer (score 0):

You should either:

1. Store the each new request as a separate row with a timestamp
2. Make a routine to take a "snapshot" of the total amount in specific period of time.

Example: every 3hrs you read the total amount and store it in another place so you can read it later.